# issue 'attempt to index global 'base'' within protocol fields creation

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

i try to write dissector on lua for wireshark. i need to parse header field version = 4 bytes (0x00000000)

my code:

```
do 

    local asc_sccp =Proto("asc_sccp", "ASC Skinny Client Control Protocol") 

    local f =asc_sccp.fields 


    f.length = ProtoField.bytes("asc_sccp.length", "length")  
    f.version =ProtoField.uint8("asc_sccp.version", "version", base.HEX, 0xC)



    function asc_sccp.init() 
    end  


    function asc_sccp.dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)

        local subtree = tree:add (asc_sccp, buffer())
        local offset = 0

        pinfo.cols.protocol = asc_sccp.name

        local length = buffer (offset, 4)

        subtree:add (f.length, length)
        subtree:append_text ("Data length: " .. length) 

        offset = offset + 4 

        local version = buffer (offset, 4)

        subtree:add (f.version, version)
        subtree:append_text ("    Version: " .. version)


    end

    local tcp_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port") 
    tcp_table:add(2000, asc_sccp)  

end
```

Why i am getting error 'attempt to index global 'base' (a nil value)' ?
Could you please help, i looked through a lot of dissector example but i can't find solution

Comment: What version of Wireshark are you running? And which OS (Windows or *nix)?

Comment: i use Wireshark 1.6.7 OS Windows

Answer (score 2):

This may be happening because `init.lua` isn't installed. This can happen in Redhat-based distributions (Fedora, Centos, RHEL etc.) if the development packages aren't installed. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489742/409638

Comment: This worked for me under Enterprise Linux 7.7 (i.e. Red hat and CentOS)

Answer (score 1):

In this line of code:

```
f.version =ProtoField.uint8("asc_sccp.version", "version", base.HEX, 0xC)
```

you are accessing the variable 'base'.  Specifically, you are indexing it by telling Lua it is a table containing the key "HEX" and trying to retrieve the value at that key.  Unless you define the variable 'base' somewhere to be a table (or userdata) and add a value at the key "HEX", lua will complain that you are attempting to index a global variable called 'base', when it is actually nil (i.e. non-existent).

Comment: It seems the question was correctly [answered in ask.wireshark.org](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/10681/issue-attempt-to-index-global-base-within-protocol-fields-creation#answer-container-10904).

Comment: there is no use to define base in lua dissector, i had to download my dissector in init.lua later, but i downloaded it in the beginning of init.lua file