# Cant find wireshark's init.lua on my CentOS machine

Tags: lua, centos, wireshark, centos7

So I'm trying to get a script working with tshark on my CentOS 7 server, but I'm having problems. The script works fine on my Windows laptop, I just put it in the plugins folder in appdata, but I can't find the similar location on linux. I used yum to download wireshark, and I have the program in another of my folders, but I can't find either of the init.lua files or the plugins folder.

When I use tshark -v it tells me it is built "with Lua 5.1" so I know that's not the problem, but I have no idea where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the Centos/RHEL camp here as well. I couldn't find `init.lua` anywhere. The *about* information was saying that lua should be available but it wasn't anywhere on the menus.

Eventually I found it! It's a part of the `devel` package which is additional to the base wireshark install package.

```
yum install -y wireshark-devel
```

Now I have `init.lua` and my custom lua dissectors are working.

***Note*** Wireshark package provided by Redhat/Rocky/Centos as of RHEL 8 no longer supports Lua at all. My investigations revealed that they just "left it out" because there was conflicts between the version of Lua used in Wireshark and the one supported by the OS. The only way I could resole this for myself was to do a custom build with Lua enabled. It may also be possible to install from an alternative source.

Comment: Works for CentOS 7.

Comment: And only until CentOS 7.

Comment: Yes in Centos/RHEL/Rocky 8 the only way we could get this to work in our shop was to do a custom build of Wireshark, unfortunately. It's an issue with RH package maintainers. A conflict between the versions of Lua used I believe, so they just left it out... In summary: The Wireshark package provided by Redhat does not support Lua.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly CentOS, Fedora, Oracle Linux, and RHEL (as of today) do not include  init.lua in their packaging of wireshark. "init.lua" must reside in the wireshark directory  (e.g. /usr/share/wireshark) before wireshark will active any Lua scripts.

Comment: But if I carry it over myself, from another machine that has it, it should work?

Comment: _"Sadly CentOS, Fedora, Oracle Linux, and RHEL (as of today) do not include init.lua in their packaging of wireshark."_ For those wondering why it's still not working in latest RHEL (version above 7), the reason is bacially: _compat-lua is no longer in RHEL (but in EPEL)_, so it cannot be enabled since it depends on a package not in RHEL. Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2133130

Answer (score 0):

Start Wireshark, and go to `Help->About Wireshark` and then click the `Folders` tab. That will list every directory, including the "`Personal Plugins`" directory, which is where you should put the Lua script so that it will be automatically loaded.  On *nix systems it's usually: `~/.wireshark/plugins/`.

Comment: I don't have the GUI form of wireshark, only the terminal version. And the location you mentioned doesn't exist on my system (/.wireshark)

Comment: Just to be clear, it's: `~/.wireshark/plugins/`, not `/.wireshark/plugins`. In other words, it's in your home directory.

Comment: yeah, that still doesn't work. It says no such file or directory

Comment: You mean wireshark can't find it, or you can't find it?

Try this:

    `find /. -name '.wireshark' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'`

Comment: I can't find it. And when I try your line of code I get no results.

Comment: That's weird. What version wireshark do you have?  There was a short time when the `init.lua` file was missing from the Windows installer binary, but I didn't hear it was for linux. Perhaps you should submit a bug on bugs.wireshark.org.

Comment: I'm using version 1.10.3